# Fail to change SO password

Tags: support, login, accounts

I have tried to change my password.

*My Account* → *Settings* → *My Logins*

I see four Stack Exchange logins: two with my mail addresses surrounded by what appears to be two Stack Exchange and further down another very old [MyOpenID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID#History). I select "Change password" for my professional mail address. I enter my current password and the new password, observing the given rules (minimum eight characters, minimum one letter and one digit). However, I only get a message that something has gone wrong. So there were also several attempts and I don't think I did the password repetition wrong each time.

I have tried to log out and log in again to make sure that I still know my current password and can write it correctly. So that's not the problem. I have tried it with Firefox and Edge on Windows and Safari on iOS. The result remains the same.

If it's important: The new password would only have contained standard characters; no special German characters.

Is there a problem here at the moment?

Comment: I don't think anyone on meta really has the insight to be able to help with this. You probably want to use the contact us link at the bottom of the page to make your account issue known. (note: give it a while. Usually when I say something like that several people jump out of the woodworks to prove me wrong).

Comment: Possibly related (e.g. version or JavaScript requirements): *[Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208)*

Comment: You can also tag this post [bug].